# Django admin - how to get object deletion link in change list?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there any possibility to get object delete url in Django Admin, in change list **template** (change_list_results.html)? I must add icons (edit/delete) on results list and try to get that links for object.

Comment: Read docs on [`ModelAdmin.list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), also [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413830/change-list-link-to-foreign-key-change-page) have been answer before many times.

Comment: But I need that globally in my new admin custom change_list_results.html temaplate not just for 1 model.

Answer (score 2):

The delete url for a particular instance can be obtained via:

```
info = obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.module_name
reverse('admin:%s_%s_delete' % info, args=(obj.id,))
```

So, just add a method to your `ModelAdmin` to return that URL wrapped in appropriate HTML:

```
def delete_link(self, obj):
    info = obj._meta.app_label, obj._meta.module_name
    url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_delete' % info, args=(obj.id,))
    return '<a href="%s">Delete</a>' % url
delete_link.allow_tags = True
delete_link.short_description = 'Delete'
```

And, then add that to `list_display`, like any other field on your model.