# Django admin: prevent add, change, but not delete

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to be able to only delete values from admin.
I wrote following code for this:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return False

def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return True
```

However, in this case I can't find link to delete object.
How this can be resolved?

Comment: Can you see the list view? Than you can create a admin action https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/ or a change list link like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770694/django-admin-how-to-get-object-deletion-link-in-change-list

Comment: I can't. Model name is not clickable after has_change is set to False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense that the **change** list view is disabled. I noticed that visiting `/admin/app/model/1/delete/` will let you delete the object.

So you have basically two options:

1. Create a custom admin page listing the models objects. Each object
   with a delete button that links to `/admin/app/model/pk/delete/`.
   Hook this into your admin somehow.
2. Set `has_change_permission`
   to `True` and make sure the detail page displays a custom form, all
   fields with readonly widgets.

I would go for 2. Because it is less work, gives you all the benefits of the change list page (filters, actions) and keeps the default admin structure. A large benefit is that the user can see what he is about to delete.

I would do something like this (not tested):

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields: 
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = []

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ItemForm

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True
```