# Link in Django admin interface to directly download model field from database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

I'm storing binary files as base64 encoded strings in a model's TextField().  I'm doing it like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  _data = models.TextField(db_column='data', blank=True)

  def set_data(self, data):
    self._data = base64.encodestring(data)

  def get_data(self):
    return base64.decodestring(self._data)

  data = property(get_data, set_data)
```

([from this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1597/)).

How do I provide a link to download these files (after decoding) from the Django admin interface, preferably from the change/edit page of a model instance?

I can decode them and display them on the page - like any other model field - but it either doesn't show or it's garbage because they're binary files.  I'd like to offer a download link.

Most of the information I can google about Django files assumes I'm taking user uploads or that I want to serve static (media) files from the webserver directly.  Neither is the case.  My files are small, used infrequently, and for administrative use only so it doesn't hurt to store them in the database directly, or have Django serve them itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs for ModelAdmin.get_urls(self): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

There's an example of how to add a view to a ModelAdmin object. Your custom view should return a response where the content is the base64 data you're storing (though you'll probably want to turn it from base64 back into binary).

You can then override the admin templates for that model to include a link to your custom view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add the custom view that returns an HttpResponse for the download.  As for the link, I initially had it overriding the admin template, but I found I could add a field to 'list_display' in the ModelAdmin (called what you like, e.g. 'download_link'), then define a function of the same name which returns a URL pointing to the download.  This also works for Admin Inline classes (although I had to paste the code twice, not very DRY?). [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413830/change-list-link-to-foreign-key-change-page) (field does not have to be a foreign key)