# django - Need references to another model from list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When i clicked to author field i need to be referenced to clicked author model admin - how to do this?

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ['name', 'pub_date', 'author',]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin class

```
   def author_link(self, obj):
        return '<a href="/admin/authors-appname/author-model-name/%s">%s</a>' \
               % (obj.auther.pk, obj.auther)
    author_link.allow_tags = True
    author_link.short_description = "auther"

    list_display = ['name', 'pub_date', 'author_link',]
    readonly_fields = ('author_link', )
```

more elegant is to change the hard link to a function in the model - get_auther_absolute_url and call it from admin

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers on SO with regards to this, namely:

[Change list link to foreign key change page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413830/change-list-link-to-foreign-key-change-page)

[Link in django admin to foreign key object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832897/link-in-django-admin-to-foreign-key-object)

To quote the above, what you need to do is define your own method, call it go_to_author() as part of your BookAdmin class, as such

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'pub_date', 'go_to_author',]
    def go_to_author(self, obj):
        link=urlresolvers.reverse("admin:yourapp_author_change", args=[obj.author.id])
        return u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (link, obj.author.name)
    go_to_author.allow_tags=True
```

I hope this helps!